# download file from BAIDU

Tags: assembly, cloud, 8051, mcu

i am programming a PLC Board with a STC MCU and like always having trouble to download program to MCU, the las version of the STC ISP programming software (v6.87) is stored in BAIDU cloud, and to register i need a chinesse phone, does somebody know or have a BAIDU account to download and send to me by mail or upload to googledrive? or knows a way to downoad directly?
here is the link from STC website:
http://www.stcmicro.com/rjxz.html

Answer (score 1):

there is a Trojan in the file

Объект:     F:\Intel8051\soft\a.rar/stc-isp-15xx-v6.87P.exe
Результат:     Обнаружено: Trojan-Downloader.Win32.Agent.xxzocm

Comment: maybe that is the cause why it still dont work

Answer (score 0):

https://gist.github.com/spcharc/8088a9e006f86ccba1e8d88b3614df5f

Grab this b64.txt

`cat b64.txt | base64 -d > a.rar`

This a.rar is what you want

Comment: IT WORKS¡¡¡¡¡¡¡ thanks, i will be testing the program this week

Comment: @user3177225 Actually you can register a baidu account without a Chinese phone number. Just google how to do that. I followed those tutorials and made my baidu account with my US phone number LOL

Comment: about getting a Baidu account; i tried all the ways that internet has,but with no luck, thanks anyways

Comment: i am using this new application, with no luck, still having problems downloading the program to MCU., In an older application, the programer identifies itself as yao yongping with mobile as  (86)13922805190, but he does not answer the phone. Any way to contact him?

Comment: i found a mirror website (in chineese) where you can download the latest software: http://www.stcmcudata.com/ but still no luck, even with a different board

Answer (score 0):

Macafee say it's a big threat so removes it.
People remember to scan what you download!